# Bounded linear functionals of $C^1[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

The space $C^1[0,1]$ is the space $\{f\in C[0,1]:f^\prime$ exists and is continuous on $[0,1]\}$. Also, we have already proved that $C^1[0,1]$ is a Banach space if it is normed by $\|f\|_{C^1}=max\{|f(x)|:0\leq x\leq 1\}+max\{|f^\prime (x)|:0\leq x\leq 1\}$

Show that for each $x\in [0,1]$, the functional $ev^1_x(f)=f^\prime(x)$ is a bounded linear functional on $(C^1[0,1],\|*\|_{C^1})$.

Also, fix $\phi:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ in $C^1[0,1]$ and define $C_\phi$ on $C^1[0,1]$ by $C_\phi(f)=f\circ\phi$. Show that $C_\phi$ is a bounded linear operator on $C^1[0,1]$.

Any suggestions how to get started with this one?

Comment: The first one is easy: the norm of this functional is at most $1$ because $|f'(x)| \leq \max |f'(y)| \leq \| f \|$. The second one is slightly more complicated, in particular you'll need the chain rule.

Comment: I am a bit confused what it means by $ev^1_x(f)$ - can you clarify this a bit?

Comment: $ev^1_x$ is the evaluation of the first derivative at $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question,let $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |\phi'(x)| = M'< \infty$ since $\phi'$ is continuous on the compact set $[0,1]$. Then, for any $f \in C^1([0,1])$, we have that
\begin{align}
\| C_{\phi} (f) \|_{C^1} 
&= \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |(f \circ \phi)(x)| + \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |(f \circ \phi)'(x)|\\
&\leq \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| + \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |\phi'(x)| |f'(\phi(x))|\\
& \leq \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| + M' \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x)|\\
&\leq \max(M',1) \left( \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| + \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x)| \right).
\end{align}
That is, $C_{\phi}$ is bounded operator on $C^1([0,1])$, and linearity is easy to see.

Comment: Would this be the linearity result?
As $\phi,f$ is differentiable, $\phi$ is linear. Let $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x_1,x_2\in C^1[0,1]$, then $C_\phi = f(\phi(\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2)) = f(\alpha\phi (x_1)+\beta\phi (x_2))=\alpha f(\phi(x_1))+\beta f(\phi(x_2))=\alpha C_\phi(x_1)+\beta C_\phi(x_2)$

Comment: No. Saying that the operator $C_{\phi}$ is linear means that $C_{\phi}(\alpha f + \beta g) = \alpha C_{\phi}(f) + \beta C_{\phi}(g)$ for all $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f,g \in C^1([0,1])$.

Comment: So for $\alpha, \beta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f,g\in C^1[0,1]$, $C_\phi(\alpha f+\beta g)= \alpha f(\phi(x))+\beta g(\phi(x))=\alpha C_\phi(f)+\beta C_\phi(g)$, would that be correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.